# how to specify a different image in css depending if the user visits on a desktop or a mobile browser

Tags: html, css, mobile, web, media-queries

Just a question about css for mobile devices,

i have an image that is 1260px wide on my website and when i look at it on the phone it destorts the website as the rest of the website is based on a 960px layout.

I have made these images to be now 960px wide for the mobile device but how do i specify in css that if it is a mobile use mobile optimized image instead of the one on the regular website.

So basically if a user goes on the website on a desktop computer it will show the 1260px image

and if they visit the website on a mobile it will display the 960px image

any ideas guys?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Im not sure if you want JS, i decided to answer your question if you want CSS3, try this:

HTML:

```
<img src="image.jpg"
     data-src-960px="image-960px.jpg"
     data-src-1260px="image-1260px.jpg"
     alt="">
```

CSS:

```
 @media (min-device-width:320px) {
        img[data-src-960px] {
            content: attr(data-src-960px, url);
        }
    }

    @media (min-device-width:960px) {
        img[data-src-1260px] {
            content: attr(data-src-1260px, url);
        }
    }
```

jQuery version:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 function imageresize() {
 var contentwidth = $('#content').width();
 if ((contentwidth) < '960'){
 $('.imageclass').attr('src','image-960px.jpg');
 } else {
 $('.imageclass').attr('src','image-1260px.jpg');
 }
 }

 imageresize();//Activates when document first loads    

 $(window).bind("resize", function(){
 imageresize();
 });

 });
```

Comment: could i have the javascript also please, so i can see both ways thank you

Comment: With jQuery: `$(document).ready(function() {
 function imageresize() {
 var contentwidth = $('#content').width();
 if ((contentwidth) < '960'){
 $('.imageclass').attr('src','960-image.jpg');
 } else {
 $('.imageclass').attr('src','1260-image.jpg');
 }
 }

 imageresize();//Activates when document first loads    

 $(window).bind("resize", function(){//Resizes image when browser resized
 imageresize();
 });

 });`

Comment: Um... this comment layout skipped these spaces, let me repost this for answer layout

Comment: sorry the image im using is a background image set in css on a div element, so i cant apply data-src-960px="image-960px.jpg".....what do i do?

Comment: It seems this CSS3 is designed for latest and updated modern browsers, it doesn't work for older browsers which support data-src... Can you try jQuery version?

Comment: its ok, i just specified the new div style within your code above img[.......] .... worked a charm!!! cheers dude

Comment: FWIW, content replacement for images did not work for me. content only seems to apply to pseudo elements - no?

Comment: Is this CSS-only solution still current? I've been tinkering with it for over an hour but seem to be having no luck. 

The Mozilla documentation suggests there shouldn't be a comma before 'url' (but this made no difference for me).

I've set up a fiddle in case anyone can help:
https://jsfiddle.net/ColiniloC/9ck9d105/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Ivan's answer, here is a jQuery version that uses media queries to be as close as possible to his CSS3 solution (which doesn't work for me in Firefox 31 and Safari 7):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mqsmall = "(min-device-width:320px)";
    var mqbig   = "(min-device-width:960px)";
    function imageresize() {
        if(window.matchMedia(mqbig).matches) {
            $('img[data-src-1260px]').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-src-1260px'));
            });
        }
        else if(window.matchMedia(mqsmall).matches) {
            $('img[data-src-960px]').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-src-960px'));
            });
        }
    }

    imageresize();

    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
        imageresize();
    });
});
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I would type the path/name of the image, in the 'src' or...?

Comment: The image would be something like `<img src="basesize.png" data-src-960px="image-for-960px.png">`.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for media queries.  You can write styles conditional on width:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/