# How to load images with CSS3 via media queries?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I noticed this Q & A on stackoverflow here:  [how to specify a different image in css depending if the user visits on a desktop or a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632486/how-to-specify-a-different-image-in-css-depending-if-the-user-visits-on-a-deskto)

His HTML:

```
<img src="image.jpg"
     data-src-960px="image-960px.jpg"
     data-src-1260px="image-1260px.jpg"
     alt="">
```

and CSS is:

```
img[data-src-960px] {
            content: attr(data-src-960px, url);
        }
```

I'm trying to incorporate this for webpage, but am failing miserably...

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div><img src="images/header.jpg" data-src-mobile="images/header_mobile.jpg" alt="Philadelphia" /></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
img[data-src-mobile] {
    content: attr(data-src-mobile, url) !important;
}
```

I have an entire stylesheet devoted to mobile devices.  But this doesn't work at all.  It always loads up:  `images/header.jpg`

Is the `url` parameter in the `attr` supposed to have something in there?  I've tried replacing `url` with `../images/header_mobile.jpg`, but that doesn't work either.

How do you use this?  I can't seem to find much detail for this on the internet at all... :(

For what it's worth here are some References to people saying that this works:

[Using CSS/HTML to Make a Responsive Website in 3 Easy Steps](http://css.dzone.com/articles/using-csshtml-make-responsive)

[Responsive images using CSS3](http://nicolasgallagher.com/responsive-images-using-css3/)

Comment: Reading [this MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/attr), I think you may have misunderstood the meaning of `attr()`...

Comment: @Passerby - Ok, so I get rid of the url from there, it still doesn't load.  The images never load.  What gives?  I'm seeing several places online that reference this now that I had more time to search.  But all of them do the same thing!  And it doesn't work!

Comment: I think the `attr()` is used to **return a value to a CSS property**, not **modifying the attribute of the element**. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/t5nCu/).

Comment: Wow, well that's just dumb than, here's what I did via jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/t5nCu/1/  I suppose that's the best I can hope to do?  Ouch, that's just stupid, why would someone tell you that you can change images in this way, when you can't?  There are tons of references online that people say will work... crazy!

Comment: I think this is what `attr()` is intended for: http://jsfiddle.net/t5nCu/2/

Comment: Well that doesn't show any images for me.  Just an empty box.

Comment: That's because no browser supports `url` type (or types other than `string`) yet. I'm just showing you the _intended_ usage of `attr()`.

Comment: In addition, [`content` property is only used on `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/content), so `img{content:''}` makes no sense, and thus "doesn't work".

Comment: Ohh, I see, so this might be something to keep an eye on for the future than.  Thanks for all your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width`, `max-width`, `:after` and `content:url`. For example:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 961px)
{
a:after {content:url("http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse.org-common/themes/solstice/public/images/logo/eclipse-800x188.png");}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
a:after {content:url("http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse.org-common/themes/solstice/public/images/logo/eclipse-426x100.png");}
}
```

```html
<a tabindex="1"></a>
```

**References**

- [Stu Nicholls | CSS PLAY | Content: - CSS Gallery](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/content100.html)
- [CSS content and attr](https://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr)
- [content - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)